# How to install laravel 7 with php version 8

Tags: php, laravel

I am geeting error when trying to install laravel 7 using php version 8. Is there any way i can solve this issue.

[image]

Comment: There is, but you should not. There is a reason the install is blocked. Some functionality will not work. Why don't you just install the latest version of Laravel.

Comment: • Welcome to StackOverflow! Please avoid uploading code as an image.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This message is telling you that no version of Laravel is available for the given version constraint (`^7.0`) and your PHP version.

Said otherwise all Laravel version from the `7.0` to the latest `7.x` (`^7.0`) aren't compatible with your PHP version (which is probably too old).

You could also have missing extensions that are required by Laravel.

Three options here:

- You try to fix those version problems and try again.
- You bypass Composer checks by using the `--ignore-platform-reqs` flag: `composer create-project --ignore-platform-reqs laravel/laravel:^7.0 blog`. Composer will ignore the "platform requirements" and will install Laravel, however it might not work well.
- You remove the version constraint and Composer will install the latest compatible Laravel version (if there is one, it depends on your extensions): `composer create-project laravel/laravel blog`.

*You can check the PHP version by doing `php --version`, Laravel 7 requires at least PHP `7.2`.*